# Python objects in a grid

Tags: python, object, grid, character

I have created a grid, although I am having lots of trouble in creating a piece which can move around! I need there to be some sort of "character" able to move around as much as he likes in the directions of "up, down,left and right" Here is the code so far:

```
 import random 


N= int(input("How big would you like the grid to be?"))
tictac = []

for i in range(N):
    row = []
for i in range(N):
    row.append('O')
tictac.append(row)
```

Also if possible, I need pieces of treasure and bandits to be created randomly across the grid.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is extremely broad. However, here's the first step to improving your code. This:

```
for i in range(N):
    row = []
```

essentially does nothing. Over and over again, it assigns row to be an empty list. You want to nest the other for loop inside of this:

```
for i in range(N):
    row = []
    for j in range(N):
        row.append('O')
    tictac.append(row)
```

There may also be more slightly efficient or elegant ways to do this, but I think it's more important that the code reflects your actual thinking than that it's perfectly efficient.

As for the rest of your questions, you need to try implementing some more code, one feature at a time, then share it to ask for further improvements. For example, maybe next you should focus on placing a character in the grid and controlling it with keystrokes, or how you're going to display the grid (GUI, text based, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, although I've already tried placing a character. I am struggling with it alot, hence why I asked how to create and place one in the grid

Comment: That was probably due to the indentation error from above. However, say the character is an 'X'. Pick a location, `[x,y]` you want to place it, then you can do `tictac[x][y] = 'X'`. Next implement the logic to change x and y based on the keystrokes.

Comment: thanks alot, although where do I place this tictac[x][y] = "x"  forgive me for my questions. Edit - There is an error message  which says list index out of range.

Comment: Following the code snippet above, you somehow define x and y (making sure they're in range - probably the cause of your list index out of range error). After you've defined x and y, you would place that next code snippet.